# hadoop.sh cannot locate/access TEZ jars: No such file or directory error

Tags: shell, hadoop, permissions, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to install [Apache TEZ](http://tez.apache.org) following the steps from the official setup guide, but it sounds like something went wrong after editting `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` to load TEZ jars. In fact, each time I invoke `hadoop.sh` I get the following message:

```
$ hadoop dfs -ls /
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-api-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-common-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-dag-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-mapreduce-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-mapreduce-examples-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-runtime-internals-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
/home/arbi/Programs/hadoop-2.5.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: [/home/arbi/bin/tez/tez-dist/target/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-0.4.1-incubating/tez-runtime-library-0.4.1-incubating.jar]: No such file or directory
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x: arbi supergroup 0 2014-08-27 16:51 /apps
drwxr-xr-x: arbi supergroup 0 2014-08-27 16:47 /user
```

The TEZ jars are in the right directories, wonder what it is wrong here!! why hadoop cannot access/locate the jars

Comment: I'm surprized that the error msgs are like `... line 44: [/home/...TEZ] : No such file or directory`. Are you sure you're didn't delete a space that separates a variable name from surrounding `[ $TEZ_FILE ]` sq-brackets? Good luck.

Comment: bizarrely, line 44 of `hadoop-env.sh` was `if ["$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"]; then`. I just added spaces before and after "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" and now I no longer have the `No such file or directory` error message. WAT!!!

Comment: Now TEZ works fine (I successfully run a map-reduce application).